# Search component effect in the mail application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

In the iPhone email application once I click on the search  bar it shifted to top and the background gets black. How to achieve this type of effect in the code? Do we need to create a custom UIView and make this shift explicitly?